# How to use a codec without installing it (portable)

Tags: windows-7, video-codecs, portable-apps, screen-recorder

I'm using [CamStudio Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/camstudio_portable) and there aren't any good codecs integrated.
So additionally you need to install a good one like [ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/).

**Q1:** It is possible to use a codec without installing it first? As a .dll or .exe maybe
<sup>Adding and deleting registry values via batch to register that codec is a valid solution for me as long as I can clean up all traces.</sup>

**Q2:** If its possible, is there a H.264 codec that could be used with CamStudio? How do I integrate it?

I simply want to record my screen and the output video should be as small as possible.
I don't want to convert the video in a second step.

Comment: Calling for shopping recommendations is never a good idea here. Q1 is possible depending on the codec I guess. I have registered and unregistered the CoreAVC AX DirectShow filter using regsvr32. As for Q2, no idea. You might need to ask the developers whether this is possible.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into automating/launching CamStudio using a script, and then make the script transcode the AVI or WMV or whatever CamStudio creates to MP4 or MKV using a portable command-line H.264 encoder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>After some more research and no solution yet, I decided to move on and searched for alternatives.</sub>

I found [oCam](http://ohsoft.net/product_ocam.php) (Screen Recorder) which can be used portable if you extract the installer with [UniExtract](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=641).
It doesn't write anything to registry, but writes to AppData folder.

The neat thing is, that it already has some build-in video codecs.

[image]