# Why does the mouse lag when screen recording with CamStudio?

Tags: windows, screen-capture, lag, screen-recorder, camstudio

When I try to record a screen capture video using CamStudio (portable version), my mouse lags so much that it is practically impossible to do anything.  Reducing the size of the region I'm capturing makes it run more smoothly, but still lags very badly every few seconds--enough to be unusable.

This problem occurs exactly the same on Windows 7 and XP

I have no problem whatsoever when I use Microsoft Expression for screen capture, even if I capture the whole screen (but I need it to be portable and to work on multiple OS's)

The only suggestion I was able to find through googling was to turn off Hardware Acceleration.  They said to go to Display->Screen Resolution->advanced settings->Troubleshoot->Change Settings to do this, but when I get there, the "Change Settings" button is grayed out.

What should I try next?

Comment: A different screen recording application, perhaps?

Comment: @AaronMiller and exactly which would you reccomend that works on Windows XP, 7, and 8 and is portable?

Comment: I'd recommend beginning your research [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software).

Comment: This is most likely related to the combination of Camstudio and the hardware you are using it on.  You don't say if you have tested it on different systems... you only mention testing it on different OSes, which could be in a dual boot configuration... in which case it's the same program running on the same hardware and thus will show essentially the same performance.  In any case, the better the hardware, the less lag you will have with Camstudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue with the same (portable) software so it's not related to your current hardware. But simultaneous capturing, encoding and writing is probably too much even for new systems.

However, you can try two things:

1. Use another codec like [ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) and look if your PC runs smoother while capturing
2. Use [oCam](http://ohsoft.net/product_ocam.php) which can be used portable.
   It already has some build-in video codecs which may improve your capture performance.

   (Extract the installer with [UniExtract](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=641). It doesn't write to registry, only to AppData folder)

   [image]

Comment: I think that will be a great solution.  I like that program more than CamStudio in pretty much every way.  The codecs in CamStudio were the worst part

Comment: I was searching [half a year](http://superuser.com/questions/552075/how-to-use-a-codec-without-installing-it-portable/622006#622006) for an alternative ;D